# How to reduce 2 quadratic forms to a canonical form

Tags: quadratics

How to reduce 2 quadratic forms to a canonical form
EX: P=$ x^2+y^2+z^2+4xy+4yz+4zx$ and $Q=xy+yz+zx$

Comment: Please provide your work.

Comment: Hint: complete the square.

Comment: Thanks a a lot. I have completed this exercises.

Comment: @LeonhardEuler_ I am a student in a universities of education.